# How to color tickets in a Trac report by component?

Tags: trac

In Trac (1.2) I want to create a report with all tickets sorted by modification time where the color should indicate the component (or whether it is closed).

I assumed that setting `__color__` by `component` would do the trick, but the report following report shows all active tickets as white:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT 
   component AS __color__,
   (CASE status 
      WHEN 'closed' THEN 'color: #777; background: #ddd; border-color: #ccc;'
    END) AS __style__,
   id AS ticket, summary, component, milestone, status, resolution, 
   t.time AS created, changetime AS modified,
   priority AS _priority, reporter AS _reporter, cc AS _cc
  FROM ticket t
  LEFT JOIN enum p ON p.name = t.priority AND p.type = 'priority'
  LEFT JOIN ticket_change tc ON id = tc.ticket
  ORDER BY
    changetime DESC
```

How do I change the color based on what component a ticket refers to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the answer by @RjOllos I chose to set `__color__` by using a case statement:

```
(CASE component
   WHEN 'COMPONENT1' THEN 1
   WHEN 'COMPONENT2' THEN 2
   WHEN 'COMPONENT3a' THEN 4
   WHEN 'COMPONENT3b' THEN 4
   WHEN 'COMPONENT4' THEN 5
   ELSE 3
 END) AS __color__,
```

This has the advantage that the rows keep having alternating colors.

Answer (score 1):

`__color__` can only be used for enums with values 1 through 5, see [documentation](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracReports#Customformattingcolumns). You could do something like this:

```
(CASE component 
   WHEN 'component1' THEN 'background: #ff5733;'
   WHEN 'component2' THEN 'background: #3339ff;'
   WHEN 'component3' THEN 'background: #e9ff33;'
 END) AS __style__,
```